# Question about migrating from ASP .NET User Controls to .NET 3.5 Master Page technology

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, css, asp.net-2.0

When migrating from an ASP .NET user control -based page with a header, footer, and menu to a Master Page using the same HTML mark-up, is it normal for CSS or javascript behaviors to change slightly?

In particular, the submenu bar text now appears run together (which looks like a CSS symptom) and the graphics on the line above it appear to have an incorrect z-order. (The menu operation is javascript-based.)

(I tried to paste images here but couldn't.)

Also, the site is very large and we've not been given permission to redo the menu for the entire site. This is a forward-only migration. (Because I know that someone will ask.)

Assuming that there are no changes in scope, what are the things that I should check?

Thanks!

- Jim

Answer (score 2):

I would examine the html that comes out of both the old and new system (i.e. view source from your browser). If there is a change there, it will probably give you a decent clue as to what is going on.

A tool like firebug in firefox is invaluable for this type of debugging.

Comment: You should be able to get the same html output after this migration. Probably there is a difference in DOCTYPE.

Comment: Great! Thanks! While we found the first answer also valuable, restoring the old DOCTYPE directive fixed the problem! I love this website! :-)